# Best way to resize a hash table

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

I am creating my own implementation to hash a table for education purposes.

What would be the best way to increase a hash table size?

I currently double the hash array size.

The hashing function I'm using is: key mod arraysize.

The problem with this is that if the keys are: 2, 4, 6, 8, then the array size will just keep increasing.

What is the best way of overcoming this issue? Is there a better way of increasing a hash table size? Would changing my hashing function help?

NOTE: My keys are all integers!

Comment: Are you writing your own implementation? Why?
The best way is **never** resizing.

Comment: Yes. And sometimes resizing is needed, because you don't know how many elements will be added. I'm making my own implementation because it's for my CS course in university.

Comment: There is no "best" way.  It's always going to be a compromise.

Comment: (But as others have said, you need to properly hash your key.)

Comment: @HotLicks Finding a way/implementation which will never need to resize (copy) the underlying array(s)/structure(s) is the best way. If one devises a way to grow the underlying structure with no need to copy data then new Map will be near perfect data storage solution

Comment: @GermannArlington - But generally ways that minimize copying are less efficient for searching.

Comment: @GermannArlington It is possible, do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hash tables often avoid this problem by making sure that the hash table size is a prime number. When you resize the table, double the size and then round up to the first prime number larger than that. Doing this avoids the clustering problems similar to what you describe.

Now, it does take a little bit of time to find the next prime number, but not a whole lot. When compared to the time involved in rehashing the hash table's contents, finding the next prime number takes almost no time at all. See [Optimizing the wrong thing](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/10/16/optimizing-the-wrong-thing/) for a description.

Comment: I found a good reference that goes into some detail on how this works: https://web.archive.org/web/19990903133921/http://www.concentric.net/~Ttwang/tech/primehash.htm

Answer (score 4):

OpenJDK uses powers of 2 for the capacity of a HashMap, which will lead to a lot of collisions if the keys are all multiples of a power of two. It prevents this by applying another hash function on top of the key's hashCode:

```
/**
 * Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which defends against poor quality hash functions.
 * This is critical because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that otherwise encounter collisions
 * for hashCodes that do not differ in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
 */
 static int hash(int h) {
     // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
     // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
     // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
     h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
     return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
 }
```

Comment: My keys are all integers so this may not be the best way to do it

Comment: @YahyaUddin It shouldn't make any difference if the keys are integers. They can still be rehashed in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

If you try to implement your own hash table, here is some tips:

1. Chose a prime number for table size if you use the `mod` for the hash function.
2. Use `Quadratic Probing` to find the final position for collisions, `h(x,i) = (Hash(x) + i*i) mod TableSize` for the `i`th collision.
3. Double the size to the nearest prime number when hash table get half full which you will merely never do if your collision function is ok for your input.

Here is an elegant implement for `Quadratic Probing`:

```
//find a position to set the key
int findPos( int key, YourHashTable h )
{
    int curPos;
    int collisionNum = 0;    
    curPos = key %  h.TableSize;
    //while find a collision
    while( h[curPos] != null && h[curPos] != key )
    {
        //f(i) = i*i = f(i-1) + 2*i -1
        curPos += 2 * ++collisionNum - 1;
        //do the mod only use - for efficiency
        if( curPos >= h.TableSize )
            curPos -= h.TableSize;
    }
    return curPos;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hashing and hash functions are a complex topic, fortunately with lots of online resources.

It is not clear how you determine the array size in the first place.

In the Java `HashMap` implementation, the size of the underlying array is always a power of 2. This has the slight advantage that you don't need to compute the modulo, but can compute the array index as `index = hashValue & (array.length-1)` (which is equivalent to a modulo operation when `array.length` is a power of 2).

Additionally, the `HashMap` uses some "magic function" to reduce the number of hash collisions for the case that several hash values only differ by a constant factor, as in your example.

The actual size of the array is then determined by a "load factor". (You can even specify this as a constructor parameter of `HashMap`). When the number of array entries that are occupied exceeds `loadFactor * array.length`, then the length of the array will be doubled.

This load factor allows a certain trade-off: When the load factor is high (0.9 or so), then it will be more likely that hash collisions will occur. When it is low (0.3 or so), then hash collisions will be more unlikely, but there will be a lot of "wasted" space, because only few entries of the array will actually be occupied at any point in time.